# php POST Method syntax

Tags: php, variables, post, syntax, concatenation

Quick auestion here, is this a correct syntax to insert `$i` variable in `POST` ?

```
for($i=13; $i<25; $i++)
            if($_POST[''.$i.'']=='on')  array_push($requestedParameters, $_POST[''.$i.'']);
```

I want to do this instead of writing all of them apart.
And how is it called so I could search in internet detailed explanation on concatenation?

Comment: Beter to use `foreach`, unless you are 100% sure the offset goes in that range of the `$_POST` global.

Comment: What you have will work (will do _something_ that is), but why are you concatenating the empty strings `''` onto `$i`?  The array key can be a dynamic expression like `$_POST['something-' . $i]`

Comment: No need for concatenation. Use $_POST[$i].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax wise, it is correct, but the single quotes are unnecessary as you aren't adding anything on to either end of `$i` - this would be better:

```
if($_POST[$i] == 'on')
    array_push($requestedParameters, $_POST[$i]);
```

You should probably check that the key exists as well, since you are using what looks like an arbitrary loop rather than a `foreach` type array loop construct:

```
if(isset($_POST[$i]) && $_POST[$i] == 'on')
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is `$_POST[$i]` since it is an integer and not a String.

If it was a String, you would only have to do this:
`$_POST["{$i}"]`

Answer (score 1):

it would just be like this.

```
$_POST[$i]
```

no need for the quotes in there.  you put those quotes when you want to add some kind of text between them.

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=13; $i<25; $i++)
            if($_POST[$i]==='on')  array_push($requestedParameters, $_POST[$i]);
```